# Is there a way I can specify the second <span> inside an element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have:

```
<label for="modalProblemLocator">
   <span>Locator</span>
   <span>xxx</span>
</label>

<label for="modalProblemLocator">
   <span>Locator</span>
</label>
```

If there are two `<span>` elements inside I would like the second to be red. Is there a way I can specify a selector for the 2nd `<span>` only?

What I tried was:

```
.inputWithLabel {
    & > label span:last-child {
        color: @alertColor;
    }
}
```

But this does not work if there is just one `<span>`, as then the first and only `<span>` will also be the last.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Use the nth-child in css**

```css
span{
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;  
}
label span{
  color: blue;
}
label span:nth-child(2){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="modalProblemLocator">
   <span>Locator</span>
   <span>xxx</span>
</label>
<br><br><br><br>
<label for="modalProblemLocator">
   <span>Locator</span>
</label>
<br><br><br><br>
<label for="modalProblemLocator">
   <span>Locator</span>
   <span>second</span>
     <span>third</span>
     <span>yyy</span>
     <span>xxx</span>
</label>
```

Comment: You'd better give an exemple with <div> to be more general

Answer (score 4):

`span:nth-child(2)` selects every  element that is the second child of its parent

```
span:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `:nth-child(2)`:

```css
label span:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
    <label for="modalProblemLocator">
       <span>Locator</span>
       <span>xxx</span>
       <span>xxx</span>
       <span>xxx</span>
       <span>xxx</span>
    </label>

    <label for="modalProblemLocator">
       <span>Locator</span>
    </label>
```